# Book where humanity is almost destroyed multiple times by an alien race

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for an old science fiction book.

In the book, the Earth was destroyed by an alien race, and all of mankind was destroyed except for a group of people who were off earth at the time.

They spent hundreds of years rebuilding themselves and making themselves more powerful. After centuries, they went out into the galaxy to take on this alien race, only to be almost destroyed again.

This happened a couple times, until mankind had reinvented themselves as almost invincible people. At that time, they again went out and defeated this race.

I seem to remember that the name of the book was **Space Lords**, or **Lords of Space**, or **Space Kings**, but I could be wrong. If anyone remembers this book, I would love to know the title so I can see about buying a copy.  Thanks!

Comment: When did you read the book, or can you give an idea of how old it is?

Comment: Are you sure it is not the pilot episode of Futurama? Just kidding, of course.

Comment: HHGG springs to mind too.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is Storming Heaven by Christopher G. Nuttall.

Excerpt from [goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17910962-storming-heaven):

> A thousand years ago, the enigmatic Killers destroyed Earth, leaving only a handful of humans in surviving space-based habitats to rebuild as best as they could. Now, the human race has spread through countless star systems, but remains hopelessly inferior to the Killers. The god-like aliens are systematically driving humanity to the verge of extinction.
>
> Desperate times need desperate measures and humanity launches a crazy plan, to board and seize a Killer starship, hoping to unlock their technology. But the Killer plan to rebuild the universe from scratch is well underway, leaving humanity at the verge of total extinction. If they fail, the Killers will be the only form of life remaining in the entire universe…

Comment: Could you please explain why you think this is the correct answer?

Answer (score 4):

**Crown of Infinity** by John M. Faucette

Alien race named The Masters roam space in their gigantic super ships, committing genocide on any other species they encounter. One destroys Earth.

One earthship survives, protected by a stealth technology called the Ramdic Shield. The commander splits the crew in to fertile couples, and equips each with a Life Bank of genetic samples and a small spaceship. They scatter across the galaxy, hiding from The Masters.

Most are hunted down and killed, but a few escape.

Generations later the humans make scientific breakthroughs and can fight The Masters as equals. The humans take the name **Star Kings**

Answer (score 2):

Your plot description sound almost EXACTLY like the 'Slaver Wars' series of books by Raymond L. Weil.  Only problem is that this series is very new - written in 2012 onwards...

Although not your answer, it is an enjoyable series of books!

Comment: Raymond L. Weil, not Weir.