# Book: aliens destroy all humanity except one ship

Tags: story-identification

Another question from my childhood:

A book, possible title being Star Kings, but nothing I can find under that title matches.

Alien race destroys all humanity, except one ship, a cruiser Challenger. The Challenger sends off multiple lifeboats with one (?) human plus germ banks in various directions, then is destroyed in hopeless battle.

Time passes. One genius in one of the few remaining lifeboats learns enough about the aliens to defeat them. Humanity re-arises and becomes the ruler of the Galaxy, possibly as the Star Kings, but become lax and are almost destroyed/wiped out overnight again. Slow recovery and...

Comment: Edmond Hamilton....

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1514772.The_Star_Kings

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89678/story-about-a-man-whose-mind-is-transported-to-the-future-into-another-persons/89682?s=1|0.5358#89682 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/123068/51379

Comment: We don't know how old you are. It might help if, instead of "from my childhood", you said something like "from the 1990s" or "from he 1940s".

Comment: @Adamant Doesn't sound much like what the OP described, does it? Maybe that's what OP meant by "nothing I can find under that title matches".

Comment: "That's all I can recall". I bet you can recall more. Was there a violent murder at the end? Did it turn out that the ship was made out of cheese the entire time? Was there a twist ending that the main character was Abraham Lincoln?

Comment: The "Related" list is an interesting read. How about http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71552

Comment: It's not Crown of Infinity....too short and Earth wasn't battling another race ASAIR. I'm 60, so the book would have been in the '60's most likely. And, again IIRC, it was a fairly sudden blow against all humanity, Challenger wasn't equipped with any special shield or equipment and was hiding in a Moon crater. It DOES sound a LOT like Crown, but.......... I'd love to read the first couple of pages to be sure!

Comment: The Challenger you speak of, are you sure it's named Challenger? One of the answers to the other question is about a book starting with a spaceship called Endeavour.

Answer (score 5):

**Crown of Infinity** by John M. Faucette

Alien race named The Masters roam space in their gigantic super ships, committing genocide on any other species they encounter. One destroys Earth.

One earthship survives, protected by a stealth technology called the Ramdic Shield. The commander splits the crew in to fertile couples, and equips each with a Life Bank of genetic samples and a small spaceship. They scatter across the galaxy, hiding from The Masters.

Most are hunted down and killed, but a few escape.

Generations later the humans make scientific breakthroughs and can fight The Masters as equals. The humans take the name Star Kings

Comment: You don't mention this happing over and over, but [this review](http://www.avclub.com/article/icrown-of-infinityi-ithe-prismi-1968-40929) says things like "centuries-spanning bit of space opera about the Star Kings and their various enemies (...) forever in the process of being wiped out of the galaxy, then coming back" so I presume this is the right answer. If you want, you can also answer [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71552) which is obviously about the same book, and then we can wait for confirmation and close one as a duplicate.

Comment: That's not the book I'm thinking of. IF I'm remembering correctly, then once humans wipe out the original enemy they almost become the lawmen of the Galaxy and it's humans who take them down the second time

Comment: After thousands of years of war, the Star Kings subdue The Masters. By this time other alien races have developed since The Masters were prevented from committing genocide. Yes the Kings do become the lawmen of the galaxy. The Masters did manage to frame the Star Kings once. Much later hostile aliens invade from a rift in the fabric of the universe and the battle was almost lost due to the first Star King coward.