# Mid ‘60’s SF book where a final human ship seeds the galaxy with colonies to survive an invincible enemy

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

A book I read in the mid-late 60’s, has humanity (except for one light cruiser) wiped out within minutes across space. The light cruiser, named Challenger, hides in a lunar crater, sends off small lifeboats with gene banks, blanking all viewports so each lifeboat heads in an unknown direction. Eventually, the cruiser rises for what it knows is a futile fight, and dies.

Eventually, one genetically modified human discovers who and how the Enemy is/works. The Enemy is destroyed and eventually humans develop (some of them) into the Star Kings. They (benevolently) seem to rule over the human race but are highly resented and many humans unite to destroy them. They mostly succeed but not all and the Star Kings rebuild.

This is **very** much like Crown of Infinity but it is **not** the book I recall. It’s as if Crown of Infinity as another version/draft of the same idea. Any thoughts? (And please don’t get into ‘Mandela Effects’!)

Comment: I hate to say it, but you're describing Crown of Infinity. [Book: aliens destroy all humanity except one ship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151718/book-aliens-destroy-all-humanity-except-one-ship)

Comment: In what way does *Crown of Infinity* differ from the book you're describing?

Comment: The ship in "crown of Infinity" was called the Crusader I think. Are you sure this ship was called Challenger?

Comment: I know it sounds like Crown of Infinity. I have it and read it over Christmas. But as much as it seems like the book I recall, it ISNT. Some differences: the genetically altered human who solved the problem in MY book was ‘wired into’ the ship, and had few visitors in a way different from CoI. The person visiting him is a male from a different ship. Also, when the humans rebel against the Star Kings it starts in a bar, and the Star Kings are almost totally wiped out. I’m not denying CoI is amazingly similar—-but it’s not the same. As I mention, it’s as if I read a slightly different draft.